# Can I retrieve information about Mobile Contacts through the FUEL API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Can I retrieve information about Mobile Contacts (MobileConnect) through the FUEL API?

Is there a way I can use the FUEL API to access contact data? Data such as:

```
- Date Subscribed,
- Subscriber/Contact ID
- First Name,
- Last Name,
- Zip Code,
- Any or all **custom** attributes
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has FUEL API call Contacts->Subscriptions been deprecated?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/has-fuel-api-call-contacts-subscriptions-been-deprecated)

Comment: No, this pertains to custom contact attributes, not just subscription status. I will modify my question.

Comment: Gotcha - go ahead and update and I'll pull the close vote. Thanks!