# Has FUEL API call Contacts->Subscriptions been deprecated?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Has the following FUEL API call been deprecated?
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/contacts/subscriptions

There is documentation on it here:
https://code.exacttarget.com/api/contacts-subscriptions

But the call itself seems to have been removed from the API.

Anyone know the status of this API call and why it has been removed?

Comment: This API is still functioning. If you add how you called it, and perhaps the error message you are receiving, we can help you get it working.

Comment: {
    "errors": [
    "An unexpected error occurred, please contact Customer Support with reference id VHlHYm1hLWxsRTZobHFpSHpTV3JmQTo3Njow"
    ]
    }

Not a particularly helpful response.

Comment: And have you contacted customer support?  I'm assuming you have contacts enabled in your account, etc?

Comment: Support has decided they're not going to answer all my questions and being that this one is not necessarily that high on the list and because it takes only one parameter, I figured I would simply ask here. Contacts is enabled in my account, I am able to perform every other operation listed in https://code.exacttarget.com/api/ but contacts/subscriptions does not only not work but it has been removed from the http://iodocs-code.exacttargetapps.com/ list.

Comment: I tested in postman, and it worked for me no issue.

Comment: I am testing in Runscope and using the exact same syntax as provided in the documentation. I have tried putting the access token in both the POST URL string (as ?access_token=xxx) and in the Header as Authorization: Bearer xxx. I will submit a ticket with support for this.

Comment: It's definitely something specific to your account at this point. Sorry for your troubles - and wish I could assist more.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific account issue, and not a programming issue.

Comment: I will put in a ticket with support and if they tell me it's an account issue I will delete my question.

Comment: Alex, if you are able to document in the question what the problem was specifically, you could post answer how you've narrowed it down and established a solution with exacttarget support. That could be meaningful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access this API call, you will need to modify your permissions in https://code.exacttarget.com.
Click the 'App Center' menu item in the top right corner and sign in. If you do not have an account, then you were not the one to set up the API credentials (like myself) so you will either need to contact the person in charge of these permissions or create your own.

I created a new Server-to-server App within the App Center and gave myself all permissions (though presumably checking all the boxes under SMS and Audience would suffice). You will have to link the App you create to your sandbox or production ET account.
Then I was able to request a new authorization token and the API call to https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/contacts/subscriptions worked just fine.

The response will only give you a list of current and active subscriptions -- those that were once subscribed [to] but subsequently unsubscribed [from] do not show.

Comment: Didn't think to ask about the app's permissions.  Glad you got it working!